# map drag event google maps android sdk cordova cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps, maps

I am trying to get an event called on map drag or I want to get lat and lon whenever the center of the map change. I am using cordova-plugin-googlemaps
which provides native api for google maps.

```
map.on(plugin.google.maps.event.CAMERA_CHANGE, function(latLng) {


alert("Map is dragging.\n");});
```

This does not work. Although events like MAP_CLICK does.

Answer (score 0):

See answer below

```
var mapdiv = document.getElementById('location-map');
var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(mapdiv);

var marker = map.addMarker({
    position : {
        lat : latitude,
        lng : longitude,
    },
    animation : plugin.google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title : 'Lat : ' +latitude+ ', Lng : ' +longitude
});

marker.setDraggable(true);
marker.showInfoWindow();
marker.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MARKER_DRAG_END, function(point) {
    marker.setTitle('Lat : ' +point.lat+ ', Lng : ' +point.lng);
    marker.showInfoWindow();
});
```

Find more details at https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps